# How to get strings from edit text and show them in list view?

Tags: android, list, listview, view, adapter

[image: I have this register window with edit text fields]

```
Permission.class

 public class Permission extends ActionBarActivity{
 EditText Date;
 EditText Time;
 EditText userName;
 EditText userSurname;

 EditText Name;
 String Surname;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_permission);

    Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
    Button cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel);


    // Create custom dialog object          
    // set values for custom dialog components - text, image and button
    userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dialog_username);
    userSurname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dialog_usersurname);
    Time = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dialog_time2);
    Date = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dialog_date2);   


           Date.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    //To show current date in the datepicker
                    Calendar mcurrentDate=Calendar.getInstance();
                    int mYear = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    int mMonth = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    int mDay = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                    DatePickerDialog mDatePicker=new DatePickerDialog(Permission.this, new OnDateSetListener() {                  
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker, int selectedyear, int selectedmonth, int selectedday) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub                      
                            /*      Your code   to get date and time    */
                            Date.setText(selectedyear+"-"+(selectedmonth+1)+"-"+selectedday);
                        }
                    },mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                    mDatePicker.setTitle("Select date");                
                    mDatePicker.show();  }
            });


           Time.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   //To show current date in the datepicker

                   Calendar mcurrentTime=Calendar.getInstance();
                   int mHour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                   int mMinute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);


                   TimePickerDialog mTimePicker=new TimePickerDialog(Permission.this, new OnTimeSetListener() {                  
                       public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timepicker, int selectedhour, int selectedminute ) {
                           // TODO Auto-generated method stub                      
                           /*      Your code   to get date and time    */
                          if (selectedminute<10){
                              Time.setText(selectedhour+":"+"0"+(selectedminute)+""+"val");
                          }
                          else
                        Time.setText(selectedhour+":"+(selectedminute));
                       }
                   },mHour, mMinute, false);
                   mTimePicker.setTitle("Select date");                
                   mTimePicker.show();  }
           });


          cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   //To show current date in the datepicker
                    startActivity(new Intent(Permission.this, Choose.class));
                  Permission.this.finish();
               }     
           });

          add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View arg0) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

              }     
          });

        }


    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.permission, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

This is my permission class with all edit text fields how to get them all on button click "Add" and add them to list view, the fact is that that in one row i need to show Name Surname and then i click list item it shows Date and Time.
I have tried everything every tutorial on google but i guess i am missing something. In fact i can get strings from edit text fields by using toString() method but most dificult part to me is how to store all this string in listitem and show them all in listview.

Comment: notepad demo from sdk samples ... question is either off-topic(if you are searching a links for tutorials - *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow*) or too broad ...

Comment: question is eitr topic, man if u cant read its not my problem, i asked for a method with could help me for making list view in custom adapter

Comment: did i wrote *save to notepad* ? or *notepad demo from sdk samples* ? there is a nice implementation of ContentProvider with SQLite as data store ... it also shows how to edit and add new entries(in "android way")... simpler way ... make your POJO Serializable/Parcelable ... use startActivityForResult ... return new entry via Intent, add it to Adapter  .... everything was in 1001 examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Create User Object:

```
public class Users {


String name,surname,mydate,mytime;

public Users(String name, String surname, String mydate, String mytime) {
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.mydate = mydate;
    this.mytime = mytime;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}

public String getMydate() {
    return mydate;
}

public void setMydate(String mydate) {
    this.mydate = mydate;
}

public String getMytime() {
    return mytime;
}

public void setMytime(String mytime) {
    this.mytime = mytime;
}
}
```

Then Create Custom list adapter :
this adapter has a constructor which takes context, and arraylist of Users  as arguments:

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private ArrayList<Users> listData;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public CustomArrayAdapter(Context aContext, ArrayList<Users> listData) {
    this.listData = listData;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(aContext);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listData.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return listData.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.Surname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.surname_tv);
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name_tv);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    //
    holder.Surname.setText(listData.get(position).getSurname());
    holder.name.setText(listData.get(position).getName());
    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView Surname;
    TextView name;
}

}
```

now add listview to your layout:

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/users_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

and now create a new layout for the list row item with two textviews one for surname and other for name :

list_row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/surname_tv"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/surname_tv"
    android:id="@+id/name_tv"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now add this code to Permission activity:

```
ArrayList<Users> usersList;
private CustomArrayAdapter adapter;
ListView lv1;
```

then add this to Permission onCreate()

```
    lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.users_list);
    usersList = new ArrayList<Users>();
```

and add this code to add button

```
usersList.add(new Users(userSurname.getText().toString(),userName.getText().toString(),Date.getText().toString(),Time.getText().toString()));
    adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(this,usersList);
    lv1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I forget to note that the new layout's name should be list_row.xml.